DNS, Route53, porkbun, Oh My
I created a domain very recently as I need to integrate resend.com into it. And me being an app developer and not a DNS guru I hit some issues real quick. I wanted greeniegolf.app and unfortunately AWS doesn't support .app as the TLD. So I went to porkbun and purchased this domain. I then went to AWS and created a hosted zone for this and copied the NS records from AWS into porkbun, a static website via S3, and voila! The website traffic forwards. Everything works, or so I thought. But now I have to add TXT and MX records to this in order to verify my domain with resend.com and things are falling apart.

I originally thought I should put these records in AWS's hosted zone section and that would work. I tried there and AWS has the Test Record button and it all appears to work, at least according to AWS. But waiting a few hours and nothing shows up anywhere on resend or mxtoolbox.com. I know they say this may take a day, but everyone online says it should be good within minutes at most.

So I thought maybe put these in porkbun, since that is the original place and where I purchased the domain. I open the DNS record section there and it immediately yells at me that since I am not using their (porkbun's) name servers that this won't work. Well, me making bad decisions over here decided to try it anyway since I could just delete them. Turns out porkbun was right, and they don't work.


So my questions are:
A) Do I need a different record added somewhere since I have a domain bought from porkbun but is hosted on AWS S3 for this to work with MX?
B) I assume I add the MX/TXT records in AWS, but any idea why they would not show up on mxtoolbox but AWS would say they are good with the Test Record button, or at least the correct value for the resend MX record I just added is returned in their little tool.
Thanks in advance. Have a great night.

tell us the domain and we can verify the dns, that is the easiest way to get good answers

Hello @djdomi - it is greeniegolf.app. I will highlight it in the question better. My apologies.

What I understand and what you need to do is

You bought greeniegolf.app at porkbun (maybe domain providing site)

Change porkbun's nameservers to your "AWS nameservers" (It looks like ns-1770.awsdns-29.co.uk
ns-326.awsdns-40.com
ns-617.awsdns-13.net
ns-1382.awsdns-44.org..) <- You can get this information at your AWS Route53 "NS"

Now, at AWS Route 53, you can add your MX and TXT records.


--- At Step 2 (Changing nameserver to AWS, it could take max 24 hours to be applied worldwide)

This was the correct way. What made me question myself was the Test Record button in AWS was showing correct, but mxtoolbox could not find it (and neither could the mail host I wanted to use). It looks like the Test Record button in AWS is slightly deceiving and should not be trusted. I was just impatient. In the words of Tom Petty, the waiting is the hardest part. Thank you!
